# Unity OSX Standalone Player not storing local data

Tags: macos, save, unity-game-engine, productbuild

I'm using Unity 3.5, trying to make a standalone OSX player for my application. Everything goes quite swimmingly until I make a pkg from it using productbuild.

The syntax for my productbuild line is as follows:

`productbuild --component ProjectName.app "/Applications" --sign "$signingid" ProjectName.pkg`

Although this initially seems to work, and produces a pkg file that seems to install the application correctly after asking for permission from a superuser to do so, when I run the installed application, however, I discovered that it was not keeping my save data. `Application.datapath` evidently, is set to "/Applications/ProjectName.app/Contents/" in this case, and is not world-writable.

As far as I can see, I have two possible solutions: The first is to find some way to make sure that `Application.datapath` **is** writable when my application begins.  I do not know how I might go about this, however.   The only other solution I can see is to make all the necessary changes to my application such that it no longer assumes that `Application.datapath` is writable, and I will need to establish another location to save my persistent data.  If I take this latter approach, I will need also need to know if Unity provides a facility for getting a directory that I can store such data at, because I do not currently know of one.

If there are other approaches beyond the two I've outlined above, I'm definitely open to alternatives, but if anyone can help me wade through what I need to know to accomplish either of the above, I would be equally appreciative on that front as well.

Thanks in advance for any assistance anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.datapath` is where the app is stored and owned by root. To get the directory for storing persistent data between runs you need [Application.persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) which is by default somewhere under *~/Library/*. I haven't used the OSX stand-alone player but  at least for editor player and iOS it works that way.

Comment: D'oh!   I completely missed that property!  Thank you!  That's exactly what I needed to know.